# Sorting any data type array with void pointer?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, void-pointers

I am sorting an array of any data type (in ascending order) with the function which takes arguments as ***void *pointer, int size, and int data_type***. I am able to sort the array with the help of the following function, but the problem is, there is so much repetition of code. In the if blocks  repeating the following code four times in the same function, **which is not a good approach in programming, and also it is against in DRY(don't repeat yourself) saying.**

```
         int temp = 0;
       
        //Sort the char_array in ascending order
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            {
                if (char_arr[i] > char_arr[j])
                {
                    temp = char_arr[i];
                    char_arr[i] = char_arr[j];
                    char_arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Complete code is below**

```
// ! sorting funtion for all data types
void sort_any_data_type(void *arr, int size, int data_type)
{
    // ! data_type 1 = int,data_type 2 = float,data_type 3 = double,data_type 4 = char

    if (data_type == 1)
    {   
        int *int_arr = (int *)arr;
        int temp = 0;
        // sort()
        //Sort the int_array in ascending order
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            {
                if (int_arr[i] > int_arr[j])
                {
                    temp = int_arr[i];
                    int_arr[i] = int_arr[j];
                    int_arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (data_type == 2)
    {
        float *float_arr = (float *)arr;
        int temp = 0;
        // sort()
        //Sort the float_array in ascending order
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            {
                if (float_arr[i] > float_arr[j])
                {
                    temp = float_arr[i];
                    float_arr[i] = float_arr[j];
                    float_arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (data_type == 3)
    {
        double *double_arr = (double *)arr;
        int temp = 0;
        // sort()
        //Sort the double_array in ascending order
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            {
                if (double_arr[i] > double_arr[j])
                {
                    temp = double_arr[i];
                    double_arr[i] = double_arr[j];
                    double_arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (data_type == 4)
    {
        char *char_arr = (char *)arr;
        int temp = 0;
        // sort()
        //Sort the char_array in ascending order
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            {
                if (char_arr[i] > char_arr[j])
                {
                    temp = char_arr[i];
                    char_arr[i] = char_arr[j];
                    char_arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**What I want is looks like below. Or something equivalent that solves my problem**

For one week trying to solve it, I did so much research but unfortunately couldn't get a proper solution.
Thank you in advance.

```
void sort_any_data_type(void *arr, int size, int data_type)
{
    int *array = (int*)arr;
    switch (data_type)
    {
    case 1:
        array = (int *)arr;
        break;
    case 2:
        array = (float *)arr;
        break;
    case 3:
        array = (double *)arr;
        break;
    case 4:
        array = (char *)arr;
    default:
        break;
    }
    int temp = 0;
  
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (array[i] > array[j])
            {
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to look at [`qsort()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort). This is how a truly generic sorting looks like.

Comment: I suggest you take a hint from the C standard library and [the `qsort` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort): Take an argument which is a comparator function. It's then up to the caller to handle the comparison needed.

Comment: BTW, I think that as written you need to change the type of `temp` to match the type begin sorted in each `if` block.

Comment: @DaveCosta  What type should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach will not work in C because types must be defined. C lacks support for C++-like templates. There are two practiced approaches for construction of generic algorithms.

1. Using `void*`
2. Using macros

Approach 1. is used in standard function `qsort()`. The manual is easily available. Usually it results in less efficient code especially for types of small size (like `char` or `int`).

Approach 2.
Use a macro to generate a function that will sort data of specific type:

```c
#define DEFINE_SORT(FNAME, TYPE) \
void FNAME(TYPE* array, int size) { \
    TYPE temp = 0;    \
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)  { \
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) { \
            if (array[i] > array[j]) { \
                temp = array[i]; \
                array[i] = array[j]; \
                array[j] = temp; \
            } \
        } \
    } \
}
```

Instantiate it for relevant types.

```c
DEFINE_SORT(sort_char, char)
DEFINE_SORT(sort_int, int)
DEFINE_SORT(sort_float, float)
DEFINE_SORT(sort_double, double)
```

And finally dispatch it in `sort_any_data_type()`

```c
void sort_any_data_type(void *arr, int size, int data_type) {
    if (data_type == 1) sort_int(arr, size);
    if (data_type == 2) sort_float(arr, size);
    if (data_type == 3) sort_double(arr, size);
    if (data_type == 4) sort_char(arr, size);
}
```

This dispatcher takes advantage from automatic conversion between `void*` and other pointer types.

However working with `void*` and magic numbers to identify types is cumbersome and error prone.

Let me propose a superior (IMO) solution.

In C11 the [Generic Selection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) was introduced what allows to dispatch expression by their type

```c
#define SORT(array, size) \
  _Generic((array),       \
    int*: sort_int,       \
    float*: sort_float,   \
    double*: sort_double, \
    char*: sort_char      \
  )(array, size)
```

The `_Generic` is used to select a proper function pointer to the sorting function.

Example usage:

```
int main() {
    int iarr[] = {3, 2, 5};
    SORT(iarr, 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) printf("%d ", iarr[i]);
    puts("");

    float farr[] = {3.1, 2.2, 5.6, -12};
    SORT(farr, 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) printf("%f ", farr[i]);
    puts("");

    char carr[] = "hello world";
    SORT(carr, sizeof carr - 1);
    puts(carr);
}
```

prints:

```
2 3 5 
-12.000000 2.200000 3.100000 5.600000
 dehllloorw
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried with macro as you wrote upper as an answer. I am getting an error. Can you give the full solution? I want to ask, Do I have to create separate functions for all data types like sort_int, sort_float, sort_double? My goal was to just do with one function. Even with the help of macro we have to create multiple functions?  Thank you for giving your time.

Comment: I know the concept of _Genecric, but here I am not able to understand, You defined SORT macro but where it is called?

Comment: @mRveli One could write `int a[]={3,2,5}; SORT(a,3);`. I'll update the answer to be more focused on the question.

Comment: @mRveli, it could be done with a single function and using a macro to generate code blocks that do the sorting.

Comment: Thank you so much. My words are not enough to thank you. Stay blessed.